# Absolute positioned div with width 100% overflows in Bootstrap 4 col

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I try to position a div with width 100 percent in a Bootstrap 4.1 col `absolute` to attach it to the bottom. But my problem is, that it overflows on the right. I assigned `position: relative;` to the parents but nothing worked.

Any idea?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RyVPZe

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

This issue is because of parent `<div class="col">` has style `padding-left: 15px; padding-right 15px` where as child `<div class="image-text p-4">` has `position: absolute`. As absolute position ignores padding of parent (refer: [Absolute positioning ignoring padding of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115344/absolute-positioning-ignoring-padding-of-parent)) width of you child is `expected width` + `padding-left` + `padding-right`.

You can tackle this by using one of the following:

- Remove padding from the parent if not required `<div class="col" style="padding:0">`. example: https://codepen.io/prasadkothavale/pen/jxmbww
- If you want to keep padding then you will need to add a wrapper `<div class="wrapper">` over absolute child `<div class="image-text p-4">` and add following CSS:

  .wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
    }

and remove `position: absolute; bottom: 0; width: 100%` from the child. Please refer example: https://codepen.io/prasadkothavale/pen/xjdwjB

Answer (score 3):

please use **left: 0px;** like (scss)and use class in row **no-gutters**

```
<div class="row no-gutters"></div>

.image-box {
.image-text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    left: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
}
```